# Update HTML canvas height on scroll

Tags: javascript, canvas, scroll, html5-canvas

I want to add a drawing canvas on top of a website that stretches for the whole height of a website.

I specified 
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
and it seems to work for the viewport, but when I scroll, I cannot draw bellow it.

I assume I need to update the canvas.height every time I scroll down, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

Here is the code:

```
window.addEventListener ("load", () => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector ("#canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext ("2d");

//Resizing

canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

//Variables

let painting = false;

function startPosition (e){
  painting = true;
  draw (e);
}
function finishedPosition (){
  painting = false;
  ctx.beginPath();
}


function draw (e){
  if (!painting) return;
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";

  ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}


//Event listeners

canvas.addEventListener ("mousedown", startPosition);
canvas.addEventListener ("mouseup", finishedPosition);
canvas.addEventListener ("mousemove", draw);


});
```

I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be due to the use of `window.innerHeight`. Try using `document.querySelector('body').clientHeight` as that should give you the height of the entire body of the page.

Also, use `MouseEvent.pageX` and `.pageY` because `.clientY` will not update when the user scrolls the page.